# How to write a map function with a type using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my type:

```
type MapProps = {
  cb_message_id: string,
  date: string,
  name: string,
  phone: string,
  email: string,
  message: string
}
```

Here is my map function:

```
{messageData.map((e: MapProps) => {
   return (
     <Container key={e.cb_message_id} className="flex-col mb-5 px-6 py-4">
        <p>{new Date(e.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.name}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.phone}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.email}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.message}</p>
     </Container>
   )
})}
```

I'm getting this TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '(e: MapProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number, array: {}[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MapProps': cb_message_id, date, name, phone, and 2 more.
```

How do I write the map function in a way that does not cause a TypeScript error? The function works, it's just causing the TypeScript error.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the code like this made the typescript error go away:

```
const messageData: MapProps[] = [/* ... */];

{messageData.map(e => {
   return (
     <Container key={e.cb_message_id} className="flex-col mb-5 px-6 py-4">
        <p>{new Date(e.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.name}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.phone}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.email}</p>
        <p className="mt-1">{e.message}</p>
     </Container>
   )
})}
```

Comment: you should paste the full component, around the `map` call. if `messageData` was untyped you probably have room to improve other areas of the program